# Is there a way to sort parallel arrays that both contain strings using a selection sort?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, selection-sort

I have to write a program that takes 2 parallel arrays, one with the title of five books and then another with the publication dates for the books. All of the examples I have seen using a selection sort are sorting integers for smallest to largest. Is there a way to change the string dates into a numeric value later on in the program. I am supposed to display the initial list first and then again after it has been ordered.

Here is my code for the arrays.

```
 function getBooks() {

var bookTitles = new Array();
bookTitles[0] = " To Kill a Mockingbird ";
bookTitles[1] = " Jaws ";
bookTitles[2] = " Don Quixote ";
bookTitles[3] = " Moby-Dick ";
bookTitles[4] = " Northern Lights ";    

var bookDates = new Array();
bookDates[0] = " July 11, 1960 ";
bookDates[1] = " Febuary 1, 1974 ";
bookDates[2] = " July 11, 1615 ";
bookDates[3] = " October 18, 1851 ";
bookDates[4] = " November 12, 1995 ";

document.getElementById("book_output").innerHTML = bookTitles + "</br> " + bookDates;
}
```

HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CIS 223 Lab Assignment #9</title>
</head>
<body onload="getBooks()">
<script type="text/javascript" src="Drackley_Lab9_2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<h3 id="book_output"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make Date objects from your dates, for each date `getTime()`.  Sort with that.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: You can use every kind of sorting algorithm on a parallel array. Just always assign/swap/copy/slice both arrays at once using the same index.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is to combine the two arrays into an array of objects with a timestamp (from converting the date string into a Date object) and then sort that array based on the timestamps. You can then use the sorted array to generate your output HTML:

```js
var bookTitles = new Array();
bookTitles[0] = " To Kill a Mockingbird ";
bookTitles[1] = " Jaws ";
bookTitles[2] = " Don Quixote ";
bookTitles[3] = " Moby-Dick ";
bookTitles[4] = " Northern Lights ";

var bookDates = new Array();
bookDates[0] = " July 11, 1960 ";
bookDates[1] = " February 1, 1974 ";
bookDates[2] = " July 11, 1615 ";
bookDates[3] = " October 18, 1851 ";
bookDates[4] = " November 12, 1995 ";

books = bookTitles
  .map((e, i) => ({
    title: e,
    date: bookDates[i],
    ts: new Date(bookDates[i]).getTime()
  }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.ts - b.ts)
  
result = document.getElementById('result')

result.innerHTML = '<table>' +
  books.map(o => '<tr><td>' + o.title + '</td><td>' + o.date + '</td></tr>').join('') +
  '</table>'
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: +1 to this. You don't have to use parallel arrays in JavaScript because JavaScript allows objects in arrays. Beyond that, JavaScript arrays can be sorted with passed-in evaluator functions, making them very powerful with sort, filter, reduce functions.

I believe parallel arrays are a convention of other languages which don't allow objects in arrays, making them an anti-pattern in JavaScript.

Comment: @ChrisN entirely agree. An array of objects would have been a far better structure to start with. It also prevents issues with keeping alignment of values in the parallel arrays the same (e.g. by sorting some of them but not all).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your dates into integers using `Date.parse()`.

```js
console.log(Date.parse(" July 11, 1960 "));
console.log(Date.parse(" Febuary 1, 1974 "));
console.log(Date.parse(" November 12, 1995 "));
```